# How do I setup the Actions/Outlets for 2 radio buttons, a calculate button, and a graph output in XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, vnc

[image: Screenshot of current setup]

The image above is a screenshot of what I've set up in my storyboard. I have 2 radio buttons, 3 static values, and a final calculate button.

The way it works is this:

1. User selects either radio button #1 or radio button #2. If she selects radio button #2, she must select a file from disk. This file will then be parsed by the function linked to the calculate button.
2. The user must provide the 3 static values in order for this to work.
3. After pressing the calculate button, the function will calculate some things and eventually feed some data into the graph to the Container View on the right.

Here's the catch - I am doing this all through VNC viewer, so I cannot ctrl + drag. I need to know how to set this all up using the Connections Inspector menu (which is the alternative for users who cannot ctrl + drag):

[image]

Does anyone know how?